# Can I use Samsung fingerprint to authenticate users in my app?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, samsung-mobile-sdk

I was going through the Samsung SDK which supports "Pass" Fingerprint recognition as per the given link : http://developer.samsung.com/samsung-mobile#pass.

Can I use this Fingerprint recognition for authentication of our application?
Does any one have Samsung S5 and is this feature tested on this device our a third party app?

Answer (score 2):

- First please be sure about the tag as it does not belong to
  android.Its just samsung sdk going by the link you provided.
- Second for the testing part of the fingerprint on Samsung S5 mobile
  you could test it on the Emulator with the specified configuration of
  the phone model due to unavailability of the phone right now.
- Third for doing this you would need to integrate your eclipse with the samsung sdk 
  [link](http://developer.samsung.com/samsung-mobile#pass). (OR)
- If you just want to test the app in the Android adt emulator then you could simply download the Galaxy S5 emulator on [developer.samsung.com](http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks) and do the required test you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use it for authenticate your apps users, but they should use S5 for their authentications.

For more info see the YouTube video [[Tutorial] Security With Pass SDK on the Samsung Developers channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=79DmrMfett8)