# Is fingerprint scanning is possible through any android device?

Tags: android, sqlite, sdk, android-support-library, scanning

I want to know if I can develop an application that users touch the screen and their fingerprint get scanned and  registered. If it is possible, is there any library or sdk to store and retrieve and detect finger prints.

Comment: Check - http://stackoverflow.com/q/24361482/2603900 but only for supported samsung devices

Answer (score 0):

No, scanning fingerprints by touching the screen would be an hardware feature and is not available on any of the common phones which people use.

You can use home button fingerprint scanners but I would not suggest going that route as number of people in possession of an android device with such feature is scarce.

So, to clearly answer your question - No, not possible. Not yet.

**Edit:**

As not many devices come with Fingerprint scanning hardware modules, it might not be a good idea to implement app lock and unlock using fingerprint. However, if you want to do it just for devices which come with Fingerprint scanning ability (mostly Samsung, in case of android), you can check Samsung [Pass SDK](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy#pass)

> Pass SDK allows you to use fingerprint recognition features in your application. With Pass SDK, you can provide reinforced security, since you can identify whether the current user actually is the authentic owner of the device.

I'd like to stress once again that scanning fingers using screen (as you have asked in your original question) is not possible and implementing home button fingerprint scanning is also not a very practical way to go if you are not using it for financial transaction authentications.

Comment: Home Button fingerprint scanner means i.e. coming in device such s5 iphone 5 ,6 .

Comment: Yes, But only a few (Samsung S5, HTC one Max etc) would be able to support it. If you are developing an app for a particular kind of device which you'd be using at your organisation, it's alright but for a broader use-case, no.

Comment: so what should i do now if i want to implement such functionality will it work in all device or not and one more thing the nearly which device need means device requirements for scanning the fingerprints and also need to know brief idea about the process and is there any sdk or api available for this fingerprint scanning .

Comment: No, it will not work on all devices. It will work only on devices which have fingerprint scanner built-in in their hardware. And if you wish to stick with just some Samsung models which do come with fingerprint scanner, you can find the SDK to start with [here](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy#pass). May I know what your app will do and is it supposed to be used by common public or within an organization?

Comment: just need to integrate into the app to lock and unlock

Comment: Vivek Patel have you worked on wearble device have little bit doubt need to ask .

Comment: Please accept this question (if you're satisfied with the answer). And then ask what you want to as a separate question. :)

Comment: i m satisfied with this answer and my next question is that i need some information regarding wearable device

Comment: @amitgahlot In that case, you need to accept the answer by clicking that 'tick' button next to the answer. To ask a new question, please open a new question so everybody in the community sees the question. Asking another question in a comment is not really appreciated. I'd definitely take a look and help if I can.

Comment: @amitgahlot Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) page and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) page for more details about what I am talking about.